# How do I revert back to my original CSS animations after overriding with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I currently have a program that using CSS animations only to make a 3d cube, rotate the cube in an infinite animation, and then when one of the faces is clicked - that face opens up to cover the entire screen. I did this by adding an event listener to pause the cube animation when one of the faces was clicked, and when clicked again the animation would continue. However this brought a slight issue. Sometimes If I were to click on the face of a square while it was rotating, the face would scale up properly, however it would be rotated and look very odd on the screen.

CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #121212;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 100px;
}

#cube {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  top: calc(50%);
  left: calc(50%);
  position: absolute;
  animation: rotateCube 12s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateCube {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 1 */
  }
  7% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 1 */
  }
  17% {
    transform: rotateY(0.75turn) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 2 */
  }
  23% {
    transform: rotateY(0.75turn) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 2 */
  }
  33% {
    transform: rotateY(0.25turn) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 3 */
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotateY(0.25turn) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 3 */
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0.75turn); /* Page 4 */
  }
  57% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0.75turn); /* Page 4 */
  }
  67% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0.25turn); /* Page 5 */
  }
  73% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0.25turn); /* Page 5 */
  }
  83% {
    transform: rotateY(0.5turn) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 6 */
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotateY(0.5turn) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 6 */
  }
}

.face {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: #555 solid 0.5px;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(1em);
}
.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(1em);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1em);
}
.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(1em);
}
.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(1em);
}
.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(1em);
}

iframe {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Cube Toggles */

#cube label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}

#cube input {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -5;
}

#toggle-1:checked ~ iframe,
#toggle-2:checked ~ iframe,
#toggle-3:checked ~ iframe,
#toggle-4:checked ~ iframe,
#toggle-5:checked ~ iframe,
#toggle-6:checked ~ iframe {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="cube">
      <!-- Page 1 -->
      <div class="face front">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1" /><label
          for="toggle-1"
          class="js-toggle"
          toggle1
        ></label
        ><iframe src="/Cube Page Layout/page-1.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <!-- Page 2 -->
      <div class="face right">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-2" /><label
          for="toggle-2"
          class="js-toggle"
          toggle2
        ></label
        ><iframe src="/Cube Page Layout/page-2.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <!-- Page 3 -->
      <div class="face left">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-3" /><label
          for="toggle-3"
          class="js-toggle"
          toggle3
        ></label
        ><iframe src="/Cube Page Layout/page-3.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <!-- Page 4 -->
      <div class="face top">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-4" /><label
          for="toggle-4"
          class="js-toggle"
          toggle4
        ></label
        ><iframe src="/Cube Page Layout/page-4.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <!-- Page 5 -->
      <div class="face bottom">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-5" /><label
          for="toggle-5"
          class="js-toggle"
          toggle5
        ></label
        ><iframe src="/Cube Page Layout/page-5.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <!-- Page 6 -->
      <div class="face back">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-6" /><label
          for="toggle-6"
          class="js-toggle"
          toggle6
        ></label
        ><iframe src="/Cube Page Layout/page-6.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="/Cube Page Layout/animations.js">
            const jstoggles = document.getElementsByClassName("js-toggle");
      for (const jstoggle of jstoggles) {
        jstoggle.addEventListener("click", function pauseAnimation() {
          const animate = document.getElementById("cube");
          const running = animate.style.webkitAnimationPlayState || "running";
          animate.style.animationPlayState = running === "running" ? "paused" : "running";
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To try to fix this I added a little bit of JavaScript code to align the individual faces depending on which one is clicked by animating the cube to rotate properly, however if I click off of the face the animation of the cube rotating is no longer playing.

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #121212;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 100px;
}

#cube {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  top: calc(50%);
  left: calc(50%);
  position: absolute;
  animation: rotateCube 12s infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateCube {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 1 */
  }
  7% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 1 */
  }
  17% {
    transform: rotateY(0.75turn) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 2 */
  }
  23% {
    transform: rotateY(0.75turn) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 2 */
  }
  33% {
    transform: rotateY(0.25turn) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 3 */
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotateY(0.25turn) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 3 */
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0.75turn); /* Page 4 */
  }
  57% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0.75turn); /* Page 4 */
  }
  67% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0.25turn); /* Page 5 */
  }
  73% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0.25turn); /* Page 5 */
  }
  83% {
    transform: rotateY(0.5turn) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 6 */
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotateY(0.5turn) rotateX(0deg); /* Page 6 */
  }
}

.face {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  position: absolute;
  margin: -1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: #555 solid 0.5px;
}

.front {
  transform: translateZ(1em);
}
.right {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(1em);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1em);
}
.left {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(1em);
}
.top {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(1em);
}
.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(1em);
}

iframe {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* Cube Toggles */

#cube label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}

#cube input {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -5;
}

#toggle-1:checked ~ iframe,
#toggle-2:checked ~ iframe,
#toggle-3:checked ~ iframe,
#toggle-4:checked ~ iframe,
#toggle-5:checked ~ iframe,
#toggle-6:checked ~ iframe {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="cube">
      <!-- Page 1 -->
      <div class="face front">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1" /><label
          for="toggle-1"
          class="js-toggle"
          toggle1
        ></label
        ><iframe src="/Cube Page Layout/page-1.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <!-- Page 2 -->
      <div class="face right">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-2" /><label
          for="toggle-2"
          class="js-toggle"
          toggle2
        ></label
        ><iframe src="/Cube Page Layout/page-2.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <!-- Page 3 -->
      <div class="face left">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-3" /><label
          for="toggle-3"
          class="js-toggle"
          toggle3
        ></label
        ><iframe src="/Cube Page Layout/page-3.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <!-- Page 4 -->
      <div class="face top">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-4" /><label
          for="toggle-4"
          class="js-toggle"
          toggle4
        ></label
        ><iframe src="/Cube Page Layout/page-4.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <!-- Page 5 -->
      <div class="face bottom">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-5" /><label
          for="toggle-5"
          class="js-toggle"
          toggle5
        ></label
        ><iframe src="/Cube Page Layout/page-5.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <!-- Page 6 -->
      <div class="face back">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-6" /><label
          for="toggle-6"
          class="js-toggle"
          toggle6
        ></label
        ><iframe src="/Cube Page Layout/page-6.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="/Cube Page Layout/animations.js">
            const jstoggles = document.getElementsByClassName("js-toggle");
      for (const jstoggle of jstoggles) {
        jstoggle.addEventListener("click", function pauseAnimation() {
          const animate = document.getElementById("cube");
          const running = animate.style.webkitAnimationPlayState || "running";

          if (jstoggle.hasAttribute("toggle1")) {
            animate.animate([{ transform: "rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg)" }], {
              duration: 750,
              fill: "forwards",
            });
          }
          if (jstoggle.hasAttribute("toggle2")) {
            animate.animate([{ transform: "rotateY(0.75turn) rotateX(0deg)" }], {
              duration: 750,
              fill: "forwards",
            });
          }
          if (jstoggle.hasAttribute("toggle3")) {
            animate.animate([{ transform: "rotateY(0.25turn) rotateX(0deg)" }], {
              duration: 750,
              fill: "forwards",
            });
          }
          if (jstoggle.hasAttribute("toggle4")) {
            animate.animate([{ transform: "rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0.75turn)" }], {
              duration: 750,
              fill: "forwards",
            });
          }
          if (jstoggle.hasAttribute("toggle5")) {
            animate.animate([{ transform: "rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0.25)" }], {
              duration: 750,
              fill: "forwards",
            });
          }
          if (jstoggle.hasAttribute("toggle6")) {
            animate.animate([{ transform: "rotateY(0.5turn) rotateX(0deg)" }], {
              duration: 750,
              fill: "forwards",
            });
          }

          animate.style.animationPlayState = running === "running" ? "paused" : "running";
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I believe this is because when I animated the cube to rotate properly for the faces it changed the actual CSS animation I had. Is there a way to either align the faces properly without animating the cube or to continue the original animation after the face is clicked off of? I've tried googling and searching stack overflow for ways to figure out how to save the animation data or revert back the data but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Rather than set animation on an id, create a class and set animation there. Then add or remove the class on the element as needed.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what it is to look like. When you click on a face, which will be at an angle, it covers the whole screen face-on, I.e. not at an angle, and then when you want to restart the animation should the cube carry on from the paused position it had on the click? Or should it restart its animation from scratch?

Comment: I am hoping to make the animation pick back up from where it was when it was clicked.

Comment: In that case I would leave the cube alone on a click - apart from pausing its animation - and the I would display a different element which represents the clicked face rather than try and do it with the actual face element.  Then when you want to restart the animation you can just do that without worrying about whether the face needs repositioning.